# Problem with creating a new lead in journey builder from SmartCapture form

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, smart-capture

I have encountered the following and would like to know if this is a bug or is this intentional, and whether there is a workaround.

We are using a SmartCapture form on CloudPages to capture Leads. The form is linked to a sendable Data Extension and is used as a Journey Entry Source ("Event Source data extensions must be sendable by linking a sendable data extension to the contact record."). Send relationship is set as EmailAdress relates to subscribers on SubscriberKey. The journey doesn't send any emails, it just creates a Lead in Sales Cloud. Lead is created, everything is fine, and in Sales Cloud it is given a proper Lead ID, for example 00Q1t00000ABCDEFGH. Now later this lead can be triggered to another journey (this can happen manually from Sales Cloud, or programatically from Sales Cloud). And when the lead is triggered from Sales Cloud into another journey, this time with email send activity, the email is sent to that lead, but it's added to All Subscribers list with SubscriberKey = EmailAddress. Which mean's it's taking into account the relationship set up in SmartCapture, not the one set up in the second journey, which works fine in case the lead is created manually in Sales Cloud (then Sales Cloud LeadID = SubscriberKey).

Can someone please clarify:

1. How does the Contact Builder know that the Lead who enters from Sales Cloud is the same Lead that was captured by SmartCapture?
2. Is there a workaround that will allow to use the Sales Cloud LeadID as Subscriber Key for when lead enters the second journey?

Comment: I would offer a bounty but I don’t have enough points - did anyone else encounter such behavior?

Comment: Besides the more user-friendly approach - is there a reason why you use standard Smart Capture forms? My approach would be to use custom AmpScript firing (on form submit) [RetrieveSalesforceObjects](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/createsalesforceobject.htm) to identify whether you have an existing lead with same email address, and if not, firing [CreateSalesforceObject](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/createsalesforceobject.htm)?

Comment: I was able to recreate this in my account - I used the SmartCapture data extension and noticed that a new SFMC Contact gets created after submitting the form and the email is used as contact key - but it still doesn't explain why a new SFMC contact isn't created when the lead is added to a journey from Sales Cloud

Comment: Hey Julia2019 - is your intended outcome for #1: SFMC to create a contact where SubscriberKey = EmailAddress (as a result of the Smart Capture & Journey 1), and #2: A second contact created with SubscriberKey = Sales Cloud LeadID (Journey 2)? Or is it preferable for only the Sales Cloud LeadID to be created? What is the intended time delay between the SmartCapture Form being submitted, and the email being send as part of the 2nd Journey?

Comment: @julia2019, do you have the object Lead linked in SFMC connector? can you have a look to 'All Contacts' list, is there a contact with the LeadID as SK as well as the one with the email?

Comment: @julia2019 In the meantime, checkout how to create forms using AMPscript:  http://sfmarketing.cloud/2019/09/22/create-a-sales-service-cloud-integrated-lead-capture-form-using-ampscript/

Comment: Thank you everyone for your input, much appreciated!! I know I can create my own form, but I was wondering why this has been designed like that, it doesn’t make any sense and it’s useless in that way..

Answer (score 2):

This is expected behavior. When you inject a contact into a journey they are established within the contact model (All Contacts) even though they are not yet been sent an email and added to All Subscribers. When you then use the create lead activity, the Marketing Cloud then stores the lookup between the `contactkey` and the `LeadID` within the alternate key store ( a system table used to maintain relationships between leads/contacts/accounts )  This lookup is then used on all downstream process and causes the behavior you are experiencing.

I would recommend using the Web-to-Lead that Salesforce has, and creating the lead originally within Salesforce, as opposed to creating the contact first within the Marketing cloud.

Comment: Thank you Eazye - can you recommend any workaround, that we could do in Marketog Cloud to be able to use this built in functionality afterall?